# Convergence or Divergence using Limits

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Use a comparison test to determine whether or not the following improper integrals converge or diverge $$\int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx.$$ I'm stuck thinking of a function to compare it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have by the L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$$
so for $x$ sufficiently large we have
$$\frac1{\ln x}\ge\frac1x$$
so the given integral is divergent.

Answer (score 4):

it obviously diverges because $\frac{1}{\log x } \geq \frac{1}{x}$ which diverges. Compare to harmonic sum/integral.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\ln x=y$ then $dx=e^ydy$  so the integral becomes
$$\int_{\ln 2}^\infty \frac{e^y}{y}dy$$

Therefore the integral is divergent.

-mike